# Getting a value from a php array using the index number

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called $alldata

If I do this

```
echo $alldata[0][6][0]["COLOUR"];
```

It successfully returns the colour. I want to access the value without using the name / label "COLOUR"

I tried this, but it fails with undefined offset
    echo $alldata[0][6][0][0];

Comment: There are 4. I will want to get the first and third

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-index so you can use a numeric index:

```
echo array_values($alldata[0][6][0])[0];
```

Or for them all:

```
$result = array_values($alldata[0][6][0]);
echo $result[0];
echo $result[2];
```

Comment: if $alldata[0][6][0] = array, then it won't echo out the value, it will echo array.

Comment: @Hallur: What?!?!?

Comment: well, at one point before you edited your post, it said "echo $alldata[0][6][0];" and the output of that would simply be "Array"

Comment: @Hallur: No. Look at the edit history: `echo current($alldata[0][6][0]);` will get the value of the array element that currently has the pointer.  `echo end($alldata[0][6][0]);` will return the value of the last array element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use foreach for this, since the array key is "COLOUR" and not 0.

here's an example on how to solve your problem.

```
<?php
$alldata = array(
0=>array(
6=>array(
0=>array(
"COLOR"=>"test"
))));

print_r($alldata);


foreach ($alldata[0][6][0] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . "=>" . $value;
}
?>
```

if you want to use the third key, then you can add a counter to it, by defining $x outside of the foreach and $x++; in the foreach.